# Why is Faculty table not mapped?

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, hibernate, maven

I'm getting Faculty table is not mapped in the query i am trying to execute but in hibernate.cfg.xml I have done mapping of Faculty
[image]

**Project structure**

[image]

**Hinbernate.properties**

```
# Hibernate Datasource
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iiitb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
hibernate.connection.username=pratham
hibernate.connection.password=prathamrathore
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
# For Debugging
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.connection.pool_size=100
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iiitb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">pratham</property>
        <property name="connection.password">prathamrathore</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">100</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="org.iiitb.bean.Student"/>
        <mapping class="org.iiitb.bean.Course"/>
        <mapping class="org.iiitb.bean.Faculty"/>
        <mapping class="org.iiitb.bean.CourseStudent"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**FacultyDAO**

[image]

here is the glassfish server log error

```
  WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.EntityPartWriter because of underlying class loading error: Type jakarta.ws.rs.core.EntityPart not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.]]
```

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: added code also now